# ffmpeg API h264 encoded video does not play on all platforms

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec

**Edit:** In the previous version I used a very old ffmpeg API. I now use the newest libraries. The problem has only changed slightly, from "Main" to "High".

I am using the ffmpeg C API to create a mp4 video in C++.

I want the resulting video to be of the profile "Constrained Baseline", so that the resulting video can be played on as much platforms as possible, especially mobile, but I get "High" profile every time, even though I hard coded the codec profile to be **FF_PROFILE_H264_CONSTRAINED_BASELINE**. As a result, the video does not play on all our testing platforms.

This is what "ffprobe video.mp4 -show_streams" tells about my video streams:

```
  Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
encoder         : Lavf53.5.0
  Duration: 00:00:13.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 553 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x180,
424 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 30 tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 12
kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
-------VIDEO STREAM--------
[STREAM] 
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10

profile=High <-- This should be "Constrained Baseline"

codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/30
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=320
height=180
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
display_aspect_ratio=N/A
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=30
timecode=N/A
is_avc=1
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=15/1
avg_frame_rate=15/1
time_base=1/15
start_time=0.000000
duration=13.200000
bit_rate=424252
nb_frames=198
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
TAG:creation_time=1970-01-01 00:00:00
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
-------AUDIO STREAM--------
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=Advanced Audio Coding
profile=unknown
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/44100
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=s16
sample_rate=44100
channels=2
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/44100
start_time=0.000000
duration=13.165714
bit_rate=125301
nb_frames=567
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
TAG:creation_time=1970-01-01 00:00:00
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=SoundHandler
[/STREAM]
```

This is the function I use to add a video stream. All the values that come from ptr-> are defined from outside, do those values have to be specific values to get the correct profile?:

```
static AVStream *add_video_stream( Cffmpeg_dll * ptr, AVFormatContext *oc, enum   CodecID codec_id )
{
AVCodecContext *c;
AVStream *st;  
AVCodec* codec;

// Get correct codec
codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
if (!codec) {
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "%s","Video codec not found\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Create stream
st = avformat_new_stream(oc, codec);
if (!st) {
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "%s","Could not alloc stream\n");
    exit(1);
}

c = st->codec;

/* Get default values */
codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
if (!codec) {
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "%s","Video codec not found (default values)\n");
    exit(1);
}
avcodec_get_context_defaults3(c, codec);

c->codec_id = codec_id;
c->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

c->bit_rate = ptr->video_bit_rate;
av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, " Bit rate: %i", c->bit_rate);

    c->qmin = ptr->qmin;
    c->qmax = ptr->qmax;
    c->me_method = ptr->me_method;
    c->me_subpel_quality = ptr->me_subpel_quality;
    c->i_quant_factor = ptr->i_quant_factor;
    c->qcompress = ptr->qcompress;
    c->max_qdiff = ptr->max_qdiff;

    // We need to set the level and profile to get videos that play (hopefully) on all platforms
    c->level = 30;
    c->profile = FF_PROFILE_H264_CONSTRAINED_BASELINE;

c->width = ptr->dstWidth; 
c->height = ptr->dstHeight; 

c->time_base.den = ptr->fps;
c->time_base.num = 1;
c->gop_size = ptr->fps;
c->pix_fmt = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
c->max_b_frames = 0;

// some formats want stream headers to be separate
if(oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
    c->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

return st;
}
```

**Additional info:**

As a reference video, I use the gizmo.mp4 that Mozilla serves as an example that plays on every platform/browser. It definitely has the "Constrained Baseline" profile, and definitely works on all our testing smartphones. [You can download it here.](http://www.808.dk/pics/video/gizmo.mp4) Our self-created video doesn't work on all platforms and I'm convinced this is because of the profile.

I am also using **qt-faststart.exe** to move the headers to the start of the file after creating the mp4, as this cannot be done in a good way in C++ directly. Could that be the problem?

Obviously, I am doing *something* wrong, but I don't know what it could be. I'd be thankful for every hint ;)

Comment: You should probably file a bug report on the ffmpeg mailing list. This should signal as baseline or baseline constrained, as you expect.

Comment: I updated my ffmpeg version, the problem has slightly changed from being "Main" to now being "High" profile. @SilverbackNet Will do if this cannot be solved.

Comment: The interesting thing is, when you use ffmpeg.exe via command line and set "-vprofile baseline", it works as expected. And we are using the same ffmpeg version for both the ffmpeg.exe and the C libraries we use.

Comment: This means that the problem is not in the library itself, which is good news. All you need to do is look at the source code of ffmpeg (the executable), to see how they manage to set h264 to baseline correctly.

Comment: I tried, but comprehending what the heck is going on in the ffmpeg sources would likely take weeks. There certainly is no check for some value being "baseline" (I had a look with TextCrawler).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the solution. After spending some time and discussions in the ffmpeg bug tracker and browsing for profile setting examples, I finally figured out the solution.

One needs to use av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "profile", "baseline" (or any other desired profile), AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN)

So in my case that would be:

**Wrong:**

```
// We need to set the level and profile to get videos that play (hopefully) on all platforms
c->level = 30;
c->profile = FF_PROFILE_H264_CONSTRAINED_BASELINE;
```

**Correct:**

```
// Set profile to baseline
av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "profile", "baseline", AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
```

Completely unintuitive and contrary to the rest of the API usage, but that's ffmpeg philosophy. You don't need to understand it, you just need to understand how to use it ;)

Comment: Why did you choose the profile baseline？  Do you mean that the video with profile constrainted_baseline can not be played normally on some devices?

Comment: "baseline" actually ends up being contrained baseline in the resulting file.

Comment: As far as I know, baseline and constrained_baseline are 2 different profiles of h264.  What is your opinion?

Comment: I'd agree with you, there are different levels of the baseline profile at least. But as I said, putting "baseline" into the "profile" field yields a file with constrained baseline. I never really bothered with more, since it worked.